# lost windows 8.1 backup

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-backup

so I had windows backup on D: drive, but I deleted it(because I was trying to move windows) and now I cannon't seem to find a way to get it back in form it was(it was only backup of windows and not all of my files)

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you mean you deleted your recovery partition or just a Windows Backup file?

Comment: i deleted recovery file